# Sending Ajax Request to Django

Tags: python, ajax, django

I'm pretty new to Ajax and Django and I'm trying to send a simple ajax request to a function called 'update'. But I also don't want the actual url to change in the browser when the request is sent (example www.website.com/page/ will stay the same even with an ajax request). Basically, when I try to submit the ajax request I get a 403 error from the server. I believe part of my problem could be the url mapping in urls.py...

This is my ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
   type : "POST",
   url : "/page/update/",
   data : {
        data : somedata,
    },
}).done(function(data){
        alert(data);
});
```

This is the view it should get:

```
def update(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        message = "Yes, AJAX!"
    else:
        message = "Not Ajax"

    return HttpResponse(message)
```

This is my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^update/$', views.update, name='update'),
)
```

Thank you in advance for the help.

I looked a little more deeper into the error and the error states that I need to include 
{% csrf_token %} when sending a post back. This example [how to get POST data in django 1.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020928/how-to-get-post-data-in-django-1-3) shows that its placed into a form however my request is only called on an on click function

Comment: so what is the problem ? One thing - your indentation inside `if request.is_ajax()` is quite off

Comment: I just updated the question, I'm basically getting a 404 error every time I try to submit the request

Comment: So, does `/page/` give you the `index` view ?

Comment: Is your `urls.py` included by another `urls.py` file that makes `/page/` a prefix?

Comment: the page is the index view

And yes it is included in the other urls.py

Comment: What do you get if you load `/page/update/` in the browser?

Comment: it will just return "Not Ajax" which is expected

Comment: sorry my mistake everyone, it was a 403 error not 404

Comment: Ah, then it's probably the CSRF protection. Give it a try using an Ajax GET request instead of a POST, which is more appropriate if you're just retrieving data anyway. If you do need to POST, read up on this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax

Comment: @user1186173 For Now, use the `@csrf_exempt` decorator. Once you are familiar with ajax requests, you can remove the decorator, and do it the right way - that peter recommends

Comment: The decorator worked thank you, I'll look more into what Peter suggest as well.

Comment: jQuery's `ajax` call defaults to GET unless you specify the type, so in this simple example you can just remove your `type: "POST"` setting from the call. The quick rule is GET to read, POST to write.

Comment: That makes sense but in this case I do need to post data to the server.

Answer (score 2):

Your url in ajax request "/page/update/" doesn't match from urls.py.That is why you are getting 404 error page. I will show you my line code you can try this.

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/update/"
    data: {
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
        data : somedata,
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Please report this error: "+errorThrown+xhr.status+xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

/*'{{ csrf_token }}' is specifically for django*/

This is the views:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
@csrf_exempt //You can use or not use choice is left to you
def update(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        message = "Yes, AJAX!"
    else:
        message = "Not Ajax"

    return HttpResponse(message)
```

This is urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^update/$', views.update, name='update'),
)
```

Comment: How would that look in django 2.0?